# Routing doesn't work in react when typing url in browser

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux

I have the following routes in the below class:

```
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props); 
    }

    render() {
        const { alert } = this.props;

        return (
            <Router history={history}>
                <div>                                  
                    <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
                    <Route path="/administrate" component={AdministratePage} />     
                    <Route exact path='/' component={LoginPage} />   
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

For http://localhost:12345/ the login component displays properly.

However when I'm typing in my browser http://localhost:12345/login or http://localhost:12345/administrate I'm getting 404's.

Typing 'http://localhost:12345/administrate' in the navigator gives a 404 but If I put :

```
this.props.history.push('/administrate');
```

in the render method of the Login component it redirects properly, showing the administrate component.

How come? I have no errors in my F12 console. Thank you very much.

My webpack.config.js:

```
   module.exports = {
   devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
        context: __dirname,
        entry: "./index.js",
        output: {
            path: __dirname + "/dist",
            filename: "bundle.js" // naam van de file die je genereert. die bundle.js include je in je cshtml. Wordt voortdurend geupdate als je programmeert
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
        },

        watch: true, // dan hoef je niet telkens npm run webpack te draaien, je ziet dan in je cmd 'webpack is watching the files'
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                    use: {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: ['babel-preset-env', 'babel-preset-react'], // deze heb je met npm geinstalleerd
                            plugins: ["transform-object-rest-spread"] // voor het gebruik van de spread operator
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
                },
                {             // Werkt niet
                    test: /\.jsx$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: '/node_modules/'
                }
            ]
        }
    };
```

index.js :

```
import { store } from './_helpers';
import { App } from './App';

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

History:

```
import { History } from './index'; // history 4.6.2
import { getConfirmation } from './DOMUtils';

export interface BrowserHistoryBuildOptions {
  basename?: string;
  forceRefresh?: boolean;
  getUserConfirmation?: typeof getConfirmation;
  keyLength?: number;
}

export default function createBrowserHistory(options?: BrowserHistoryBuildOptions): History;
```

Comment: @Chris I already did - no luck.

Comment: did you bootstrap this app with create-react-app?

Comment: @ChaimFriedman no.

Comment: in that case we may also need to see your webpack config and your index.html. If you are serving the index.html yourself (as opposed to use webpack-dev-server) it would helpful to see that too

Comment: @ChaimFriedman, I have included both files

Comment: Try to import BrowserRouter as Router  `import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";`

Comment: @Liamm12 Thanks, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Is it working with internal navigation instead of direct access ?

Comment: @GabrielBleu If I type in the url in the browser it doesn't work. If I put    this.props.history.push('/administrate'); in the render method I redirect to administrate.. Strange !!

Comment: Take a look at [webpack-dev-server](https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/#using-webpack-dev-server)

Comment: I've tried all these solutions as well and I'm still having the same problem

Answer (score 7):

Your server needs to deliver your app no matter what URL comes in, because your app, in the browser, is manipulating the URL. Our current server doesn't know how to handle the URL.

> The Webpack Dev Server has an option to enable this. Open up
>   package.json and add --history-api-fallback.

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --content-base . --history-api-fallback"
```

We also need to change our relative paths to absolute paths in index.html since the URLs will be at deep paths and the app, if it starts at a deep path, won't be able to find the files.

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!-- index.css -> /index.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/index.css">

<!-- bundle.js -> /bundle.js -->
<script src="/bundle.js"></script>
```

[Configuring Your Server](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/10-clean-urls#configuring-your-server)

As well you can also configure Webpack server inside `webpack.config.js`

```
 devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './',
    hot: true
  },
```

Try to use `HashRouter` from React Router Dom

```
import { HashRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";



             <HashRouter>                          
                    <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
                    <Route path="/administrate" component={AdministratePage} />     
                    <Route exact path='/' component={LoginPage} />  
             </HashRouter>
```

Comment: module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: {
            index: "./index.js"
        },
    },
I added the above line to my webpack.config.js, but still 404's.

Comment: module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true
    }, ...        same thing.

Comment: Well, are you still importing BrowserRouter as Router?

Comment: No I tried but I switched back to Router which works in the original boiler plate app that I downloaded.

Comment: See this video will help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w9-1T1D0xlQ

Comment: Will do. I think the solution is here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually

Comment: See my original post

Comment: Answer Updated! Try to use HashRouter also have you tried to configure your server?

Comment: I don't want to use HashRouter. And how should I configure the server?

Comment: I already explained that above, have you tried to follow the steps in my answer?

Answer (score 3):

Wrapping your App under BrowserRouter in the index.js is missing as stated [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter).

index.js

```
 import { store } from './_helpers';
    import { App } from './App';
    import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

    render(
        <Provider store={store}>
          <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
          </BrowserRouter>
        </Provider>,
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

A fully working example should be like this.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from '../../Components/Login/Login';
import Signup from '../../Components/Signup/Signup';
import classes from './Home.css';
import HomePage from '../HomePage/HomePage';


class Home extends Component {

    render() {
    return (
        <div className={classes.Container}>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} />
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
          </Switch>
        </div>

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @OleEHDufour can you try again removing the Router wrapping over App.js
I edited the response with a working example for you to try

Comment: I did. Still 404's when I type the url in the navigation bar.BTW you index.js is duplicate

Comment: I have seen that the question is quite old. However, I am still experiencing similar or the same issues. Unfortunately, I was not able to implement the suggested solution since React and React-Router-Dom appear to have evolved a lot since March 2018 and I do not find the "places" were the solution should be applied. I have 2 questions:

Comment: 1) Could you please tell me how the suggested solution could be applied to the most recent versions of React and React-Router-Dom?
2) All issues seem to disappear when the production build is used. Is that "normal behavior" that I can rely on when using my appplication in a production environment?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using webpack then add this to your webpack config:

```
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
```